# Conditional color coding in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, colors, fill, color-coding

I have a fairly simple question regarding Excel and VBA, but because I'm new to VBA, I have no idea how to implement it.

I have an entire column full of a color code. The cells in that column say either R, G, or Y.

I need a macro that will traverse that column, change all cells that say "R" to have a fill of red, change all cells that say "Y" to have a fill of yellow, and change all cells that say "G" to have a fill of green.

I know this can also be done by simply sorting the rows alphabetically and then changing the colors manually, but I am looking for an automatic way of doing that.

Comment: Let me clarify: I have a huge spreadsheet that basically formats itself to include all the useful information and exclude all the useless information. There's already a pretty extensive custom macro that does the above. I was hoping to add to that macro that would take care of the conditional color coding. That way, the user can just open up the spreadsheet and have the macro do all the work for them, minimizing how much clicking they have to do. THAT is why I do not want to use Excel's built in conditional formatting. I want it all to execute seamlessly when the user runs the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight the column with your R, Y, and G and apply conditional formatting.  |  Home tab > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Equal to... |  Enter your letter of choice and select the corresponding color scheme!

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional formatting. You can change both the text and the cell to be the same colour

Comment: Please see my edit above. I know that I can use conditional formatting, but this is about minimizing user clicks. I need the Excel viewer to be able to press the macro they're going to run anyway and let the color coding be taken care of within that step.

Comment: It will be with conditional formatting ... Could you explain what you want to do and why conditional formatting will not do it

Comment: Ahh, I see now what you were saying. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)`

For R = 0 To 255
    For G=0 To 255
        For B=0 to 255
    Cells(1 , 1).Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)`
Next R
```

You can use another loop change Cells row and column.